# Is it possible to set a timer to show / hide passwords in material design?

Tags: java, android, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

So, I am using androidx library, and have implemented below code in my xml to show / hide password,

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

What exactly I wanted to do is, When user is entering a password... and when user clicks on eye icon to show password... it should hide the password back after like 10 seconds and eye icon changes automatically.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It seems like it could be annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show/hide the password you can use something like this:

```
TextInputLayout password = findViewById(R.id......);
EditText editText = password.getEditText();
if (editText == null) {
  return;
}
// Store the current cursor position
final int selection = editText.getSelectionEnd();

//This is core condition. It is the key to know if the password is just visible or not.
if (editText != null
    && editText.getTransformationMethod() instanceof PasswordTransformationMethod) {
  editText.setTransformationMethod(null);
} else {
  editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
}

// And restore the cursor position
editText.setSelection(selection);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding quickly... actually showing / hiding password is not an issue for me. Its just have to put a timer on it if the password is visible and hide it if user didnt hide the password

Comment: @DarpalDhyani The point to know if the password is visible is this line: `if (editText != null
    && editText.getTransformationMethod() instanceof PasswordTransformationMethod)` . And it can work both clicking the endIcon or by code. Put a timer, test the condition and then show/hide the password.

Comment: ok got it thanks for making that clear to me. Also would appreciate if you have any resource to have a look at  `getTransformationMethod()` and `PasswordTransformationMethod` ..... never worked with it before.

Comment: The `TransformationMethods` is used by `TextView` to do things like replacing the characters. The [PasswordTransformationMethod](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod) is an "old class" which replaces the characters with dots.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It solved my issue. Setting the timer with the above code solved the issue.

Comment: Sorry to come respond back this late, But having one more issue.... in the code. The cursor position is switching to end. Instead is there any chance to keep the cursor wherever user have kept? I mean after writing something, if user adjusts cursor to some letter then it should stay there.

Comment: @DarpalDhyani It should be done with the code just reported in the answer :selection = editText.getSelectionEnd(); and editText.setSelection(selection); Which version of TextinputLayout are you using?

Comment: Hi, this is the version I am using right now `'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'`

Comment: @DarpalDhyani I don't know if it is related to the implementation inside the timer, but in any case it is better to use the 1.1.0-beta02.

Comment: Hi just an update on that cursor situation. Still not working for me. Here is my code, how I implemented. [Link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58996098/7505562)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void showHidePassword() {
        textInputLayout = activityBinding.textInputLayout;
        textInputEditText = activityBinding.editTextPassword;

        textInputEditText = (TextInputEditText) textInputLayout.getEditText();
        if (textInputEditText == null) {
            return;
        }
        textInputEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                try {
                    if (textInputEditText.getTransformationMethod() == null) {
                        stopHandlerPassword();
                        setTimerPasswordEditText();
                    } else {
                        stopHandlerPassword();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTimerPasswordEditText() {
        passwordEditTextRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (textInputEditText != null && textInputEditText.getTransformationMethod() == null) {
                        hidePassword();
                    }
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        passwordHandler.postDelayed(passwordEditTextRunnable, 8000);
    }

    private void stopHandlerPassword() {
        passwordHandler.removeCallbacks(passwordEditTextRunnable);
    }

    private void hidePassword() {
        if (textInputEditText != null) {
            textInputEditText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            try {
                int selection = textInputEditText.getSelectionEnd();
                textInputEditText.setSelection(selection);
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I managed to add a timer and also hide password. Took help from Gabriele Mariotti at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58938568/7505562)